# How do I get the top of columns to line up properly using the inline-block display?

Tags: html, css

I've looked around to no avail. I'm really new to CSS so this might be something simple. Essentially I have 4 columns that stretch across a page, and for whatever reason they tops of columns 2 and 4 are higher than the other two. There are 2 links per column.

Here is the code.

```
ul {
width:240px;
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
}

li {
text-align: center;

}

.links {
height: 250px;
width: 1000px;
top: 0px; left: 0px;
margin-top: 9px;
position: absolute;
//-moz-column-count: 4;
column-count: 4;
display: inline-block;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
font-family: 'haxr';
font-size: 30px;
height: 250px;
line-height: 30px;
color: #3b3b3b;
}

a:hover {
transition: color 0.4s ease;
color: #ff1957;
transition: font 0.15s ease;
font-size: 40px;
}
```

Someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please!

Comment: Can you show us your html?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle/codepen.io etc for us which shows the problem.  Makes fixing it soooooo much easier for everyone.

Comment: Here you go! https://jsfiddle.net/mpt3qtq6/

Comment: the `ul` element's default styles have top and bottom margins, there is a gap because of the top margin. You just need `.links ul { margin-top: 0; }`

Comment: So I did that, however now there's only two columns and the column-count doesn't work at all.

Comment: Nevermind I'm stupid, got it.